# Hive - Ways to standardize incoming date fields n hive?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, hive, rdbms

I've got datasources from all over using mysql, oracle, etc. Each datasource stores the date as a record in a table(s), but the format is not standard and can even vary from table to table in the same datasource (yyyy-MM-dd, yyyy-dd-MM, MM-dd-yyyy, yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:SS:ss, etc.).

What are some options to standardize these different date fields to store in hive? Pig?

Comment: This is an ETL problem.  Store them using native Hive date formats.

Comment: Yes, upon looking more into it, this is an ETL issue. I'm moving forward with Pig.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Sqoop for pulling data to Hive, you can write your own query to get the date in a specific standard format.

```
sqoop --options-file <Source RDMS options file> 
--query "select to_char(start_date,'mm/dd/yyyy') as my_date from SALES"
```